# Finger Touch instead of First Person Character

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

probably is too easy but.....
This Script is working well, got it from Boris Media it shows a text when the character enter in the box collider, I do not use characters I am using a 3D model so the user has to touch the model, not walk through the game.
Thanks in advance.

```
#pragma strict

var note : GameObject;

function Start () {
note.SetActive (false);
}

function OnTriggerEnter () {
note.SetActive (true);
}

function OnTriggerExit () {
note.SetActive (false);
}
```

Comment: well I am new on Unity and Script, take me long time to get result with this one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example in `C#` but it shouldn't be too hard to convert to `JavaScript` if you need to:

```
Vector2 touchPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(touchPos.x, touchPos.y, 0));

RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
    // The user's touch has collided with something now we have to check what it collided with
    // You can also use hit.point if you want to get the position of the touch in the world
    if (hit.collider.tag == "GameObjectTag") {
        Debug.Log("Hit " + hit.collider.name);
        hit.collider.gameObject.setActive(true);
    }
}
```